# Why is query not using index in Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, optimization, indexing

I have a query that uses the date index if I query for 1,2,3,4 or 5 days worth of data. For these queries data comes back in less than 10 seconds. For 6 days or above it decides to not use the index and query takes forever, if it comes back at all. If I try using an index help it doesn't seem to use the index. I tried doing a gather statistics on the index and on the table. Here is the query (9 days worth of data in this case):

```
select 

                        r.range_text as duration_range,
                        nvl(count(c.call_duration),0) as calls,
                        nvl(SUM(call_duration),0) as total_duration
                    from
                        duration_ranges r
                    left join
                        big_table c
                    on c.call_duration >= r.range_lbound AND c.call_duration <= r.range_ubound

                    where calltimestamp_local >= to_date('20-02-2014 00:00:00','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:mi:ss')
                    and calltimestamp_local <= to_date('28-02-2014 23:59:59' ,'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:mi:ss')
                     and  c.destinationnumber = 'sip:1000@company.com:5060;user=phone'
                    group by
                    r.range_text
                order by
                    r.range_text;
```

Here is the explain plan without the index:

```
Without Index
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 827,605  Bytes: 1,344  Cardinality: 14                          
    8 SORT GROUP BY  Cost: 827,605  Bytes: 1,344  Cardinality: 14                   
        7 MERGE JOIN  Cost: 827,486  Bytes: 246,552,768  Cardinality: 2,568,258                 
            2 SORT JOIN  Cost: 4  Bytes: 308  Cardinality: 14           
                1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE MYDB.DURATION_RANGES Cost: 3  Bytes: 308  Cardinality: 14         
            6 FILTER            
                5 SORT JOIN  Cost: 827,471  Bytes: 14,164,118  Cardinality: 191,407         
                    4 PARTITION RANGE ALL  Cost: 824,134  Bytes: 14,164,118  Cardinality: 191,407  Partition #: 7  Partitions accessed #1 - #1653   
                        3 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE MYDB.BIG_TABLE Cost: 824,134  Bytes: 14,164,118  Cardinality: 191,407  Partition #: 7  Partitions accessed #1 - #1653
```

With the index:

```
With Index
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 822,732  Bytes: 1,344  Cardinality: 14                          
    8 SORT GROUP BY  Cost: 822,732  Bytes: 1,344  Cardinality: 14                   
        7 MERGE JOIN  Cost: 822,635  Bytes: 205,460,736  Cardinality: 2,140,216                 
            2 SORT JOIN  Cost: 4  Bytes: 308  Cardinality: 14           
                1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE MYDB.DURATION_RANGES Cost: 3  Bytes: 308  Cardinality: 14         
            6 FILTER            
                5 SORT JOIN  Cost: 822,621  Bytes: 11,803,444  Cardinality: 159,506         
                    4 TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID TABLE MYDB.BIG_TABLE Cost: 819,841  Bytes: 11,803,444  Cardinality: 159,506  Partition #: 7  Partition access computed by row location 
                        3 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX MYDB.IDX_CDR_CALLTIMESTAMP_LOCAL Cost: 2,744  Cardinality: 850,691
```

Any idea why it wouldn't use the index if at 5 days worth of data it is coming back perfectly fast? It doesn't seem to be optimizing things since it comes back much much slower.

Comment: BTW,  version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works slower because of data and index wouldn't change much? You can easily check it by forcing Oracle to use index - specify `INDEX` hint and then compare times with index and without it for identical query.

You can also specify `NOINDEX` hint to compare times for 5 and fewer days.

Comment: I tried the index hint but didn't seem to work. It should be as follows, right? (where IDX_CDR_CALLTIMESTAMP_LOCAL is the index name)


      `select 
                            /*+ index(big_table IDX_CDR_CALLTIMESTAMP_LOCAL) */
                            r.range_text as duration_range,
                            nvl(count(c.call_duration),0) as calls,
                            nvl(SUM(call_duration),0) as total_duration from .... etc. `

Comment: @user2281976 If you are using alias to the table then you probably should use it also in hint: `select /*+ index(c IDX_CDR_CALLTIMESTAMP_LOCAL) */ ... `

Comment: Thought I tried that--guess I didn't. Yes, must use the alias. For 6 days worth of data it comes back better if I force the index use, but it is still much slower than 5 days. To review, if I choose 1-5 days in the selection it takes less than 10 seconds, for 6 days (forcing index use) just under 2 minutes. If I try 6 days of data without the date index it runs for a very long time.

Comment: I should say it turns out I didn't gather statistics on the table--working with someone else and they incorrectly said they did it. Must be a statistics issue--but why is there such a jump in query time between 5 and 6 days I wonder--there isn't a lot more data in that extra day...